# Mongoose update object inside a nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I know there are hundreds of same questions, but I've read them and can't get this to work.

What I want to do is to **update** the given **object** inside **tasks** array with given `req.body` params

 
I tried most of the solutions but probably wrongly implemented them. This is closest to what I can imagine working.

## Example document

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f421bf98bc1d33d7c646535"),
    "todoSections" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f42202b9c6c3040ea0d5326"),
            "name" : "first section",
            "tasks" : [ 
                {
                    "status" : 4,
                    "priority" : 2,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f42274952e6864b19252e37"),
                    "name" : "task 1",
                    "assignedUsers" : [],
                    "comments" : [],
                    "subTasks" : []
                }, 
                {
                    "status" : 4,
                    "priority" : 2,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5f422a6377eaa74f2e403940"),
                    "name" : "task 2",
                    "creationDate" : ISODate("2020-08-23T08:35:47.497Z"),
                    "assignedUsers" : [],
                    "comments" : [],
                    "subTasks" : []
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f42202f9c6c3040ea0d5327"),
            "name" : "another section..",
            "tasks" : []
        }, 
    ],
    "__v" : 0
    }
```

## My code

```js
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");

Todo.updateOne(
    {
      _id: req.body.todoId,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "todoSections.$[outer].tasks$[inner]": {
          name: req.body.name,
          status: req.body.status
        },
      },
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        { "outer._id": ObjectId(req.body.sectionId) },
        { "inner._id": ObjectId(req.body.taskId) },
      ],
    },
    (err, result) => {
      if (!err) {
        if (result.nModified === 0) {
          res.status(400).send(result);
          console.log(result);
          return;
        } else {
          res.status(200).send("ok");
        }
      } else {
        res.status(400).send(err);
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
    }
  );
```

## Result returns:

```
{
"ok": 0,
"n": 0,
"nModified": 0
}
```

Comment: you missed `.` after `tasks` `tasks$[inner]` it should be `tasks.$[inner]`

Comment: Thanks! It works now... It's hilarious that I spent like 4 hours thinking on this haha